# Modify classes or events in pasted content (in the case HTML) in CKEditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

The problem definition is,

Some people paste copied text from some websites in to the text editor. And the copied context contains links, images, `<p>`, `<strong>` and many HTML tags. And I want to edit the attributes of the contained HTML tags.

Sample situation: I copy a status from my Facebook feed in which I have tagged my friend and a page, and paste it in CKEditor. So it looks like this `<a href='profile-link-here' class='profile-link'>`. So when I submit the CKEditor the link is with the class **profile-link**. But usually I add a class **inner-link** to the links in the CKEditor. Based on this class I apply stylings and jQuery actions to the link where I display the content submitted.

So how can I alter the pasted code's attributes in the CKEditor?

Comment: I have this problem exactly and hope the answer you get will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack this yourself using the `paste` event that can be wired up after `instanceReady`.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    var editor = ev.editor;

    // During the PASTE event, modify certain paste values
    editor.on('paste', function(even) {
        even.data.dataValue = even.data.dataValue.replace("profile-link", "inner-link");
    });
});
```

It's not a complete solution but you get the idea. You might want to add some validation or use regex to do the replacing depending on your exact needs. I do this to fix a Chrome paste bug.

Comment: Actually you are searching exactly for "profile-link" and replacing it with `inner-link`, But the issue is, people will copy from any site. And the link may have any class or any ID. So a general solution is required.

Comment: And I guess you are replacing the words here not the attributes of a HTML tag.

Comment: As stated, this is not a complete solution, rather it gives you a basis where to work from. Actually I do use this to replace the attributes of an HTML tag. Did you try it? If you want me to complete the finish for you, what is it that you exactly need? I thought you wanted the `profile-link` gone and `inner-link` instead of it. If you just want to add it, just do `.replace("profile-link", "profile-link inner-link");`. I would also change this to a regex that checks for `class=""` and I would check that dataValue contains an "<a" etc. - an SO answer is not a ready feature.

Comment: * Complete the feature I mean, derp.